After 24.04 upgrade gdm3 only shows mouse cursor on secondary display
I have a zoostorm box with the system details as in the screen shot below.
I have until today successfully used this with a Dell 24" display as my primary and a Lenovo 23" as my secondary.
Today I ugraded to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Since the upgrade the Lenovo screen is dark except when I move my cursor over it in which case it just displays the moue cursor.
If I switch fr0om display manager gdm3 to lightdm then both screens work as expected. But when I switch back to gdm3 I get the same problem.
I want to use gdm3. Please could someone suggest things I could try to get dual display working fully again on gdm3?
Thanks in advance.
System details screen shot

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot

seems to have fixed it.
